# How could I train a keras model with one output and multiple y_true?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, loss-function

I would like to train a Keras model with only one output, but there are multiple `y_true`. Like this:

```py
def CustomLossFunc([y_true1, y_true2], y_pred):
    Score1 = func1(y_true1, y_pred)
    Score2 = func2(y_true2, y_pred)
    return Score1 + Score2
```

Is it possible in Keras?

**My thinking about this:** Maybe I could split the only y_pred to two identical y_pred1 and y_pred2. Then train it like a model with two outputs. And assign two y_true to two y_pred. But I think it's a little messy, maybe there are better ways.

Comment: I didn't try multiple y_true. But I am 99% sure it is possible. You can add any loss with `add_loss()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could slice the y_true inside custom loss function when using `model.fit`:

```
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow import keras
from tensorflow.keras import layers
import numpy as np

BS = 3
N = 5
X = np.random.rand(BS,N)
Y = np.random.rand(BS,N*2)

def CustomLossFunc(y_true, y_pred):
    y_true1 = y_true[:, :N]
    y_true2 = y_true[:, N:]
    Score1 = MAE(y_true1, y_pred)
    Score2 = MSE(y_true2, y_pred)
    return Score1 + Score2 

def MAE(y_true, y_pred):
    return tf.reduce_mean(tf.abs(y_true - y_pred))

def MSE(y_true, y_pred):
    return tf.reduce_mean((y_true - y_pred)**2.)

input_shape = (N,)
input_layer = keras.Input(shape=input_shape)
output_layer = layers.Dense(N, 'relu')(input_layer)

model = keras.Model(inputs=input_layer, outputs=output_layer)

optimizer = keras.optimizers.Adam(learning_rate=1e-4)
model.compile(optimizer=optimizer, loss=CustomLossFunc)

model.fit(X, Y, batch_size=BS, epochs=1)
```

If you are using `GradientTape` then just add loss together:

```
tf.GradientTape() as tape:
    y_pred = model(X)
    loss = loss_1(y_true1, y_pred) + loss_2(y_true2, y_pred)

grads = tape.gradient(loss , model.trainable_variables)
optimizer.apply_gradients(zip(grads , model.trainable_variables))
```

Comment: Thanks! It's very helpful. There is a small problem that two `y_true` maybe in differenct shape. I think I could manually expand one of them so that they are in same shape.

Comment: No problem, glad to help

Comment: Very nice written answer!